# Order column by alphanumeric value using sorted

Tags: python

I have a csv file with the following columns:

```
TEST1,A10001,TEST2,JPLPL
TEST2,A10001,TEST1,XPLPL
TEST3,810001,TEST2,JPLPL
TEST3,810001,TEST1,XPLPL
TEST1,V10001,TEST2,JPLPL
TEST2,X10001,TEST1,XPLPL
TEST1,A10002,TEST2,JPLPL
TEST2,A10002,TEST1,XPLPL
TEST3,810002,TEST2,JPLPL
TEST3,810002,TEST1,XPLPL
TEST1,Z10002,TEST2,JPLPL
TEST2,Z10002,TEST1,XPLPL
```

Right now sorting it alphabetically by the second column gives me:

```
TEST3   810001  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST3   810001  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST3   810002  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST3   810002  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST1   A10001  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST2   A10001  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST1   A10002  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST2   A10002  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST1   V10001  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST2   X10001  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST1   Z10002  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST2   Z10002  TEST1   XPLPL
```

However, I want to be sorted as follows:

```
TEST3   810001  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST3   810001  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST3   810002  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST3   810002  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST1   A10001  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST2   A10001  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST1   V10001  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST2   X10001  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST1   Z10002  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST1   A10002  TEST2   JPLPL
TEST2   A10002  TEST1   XPLPL
TEST2   Z10002  TEST1   XPLPL
```

wherein the sequential order of the alphanumeric key is respected. Is this possible in Python? This is my code so far:

```
import csv
import operator

reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv"), delimiter=",")
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: why should `A10002` go after `Z10002` ??? (4-3 lines from the end)

Comment: try with this `sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(1)[1:] if operator.itemgetter(1)[0].isalpha() else operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)`

Comment: @ruhaib I get an error message saying it `operator.itemgetter is unsubscriptable`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest its an internal requirement to make the entries easy to parse once they are uploaded into our system, A10001, V10001 and X10001 are part of a single group.

Comment: @methuselah, if you are saying they are in group - then that order is not mandatory, it would be enough that they go as siblings with same numeric suffix

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest can't argue with management, they want the order that way :)

Comment: @methuselah, great, tell them to do "*that way*" by theirselves